# Redirect .mp3 file to PHP script and back

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I want to redirect clients requesting the file '/File.mp3' to a PHP script that will verify the user. Then, if the script responds 'TRUE', I want to redirect the client to download the file.

How can I do this with PHP and Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*).mp3$ /mp3_file.php?file=$1
```

Please note this is very easy to hack:

```
http://localhost//etc/passwd%00.mp3
http://localhost/config.php%00.mp3
```

AFAIK, you can safely load the file using the following:

```
$data = file_get_contents('your_mp3_dir/'.basename(str_replace("\0", "", $_REQUEST['file'])).'.mp3');
```

Comment: Any way to block this 'hack'?

Comment: First of all, PHP's safe mode will block this, but you probably aren't using it =). Besides that, it depends on the way you are loading the actual file. I'll put a safe example in my post.

Comment: Sorry for driving you crazy, but when I'm accessing the mp3 file (Which is actually RewriteEngine) now -- nothing happens (no Open/Save dialog). What code should I add in order to this to work? My previous code was very easy and simple.

Comment: Ah, that's easy, use the content disposition-header. I'll search for some sample code right now. **Edit**: look at the examples at this page (use the header-functions): http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Thanks. I've placed this header along with "echo $data;". (Without it -- the client gets a 0 bytes file.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `mod_rewrite`.

Here's a good 2-part tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/